# Snoop on Solaris 10 package - relocation error

Tags: solaris, relocation, snoop

I'm trying to run snoop on a Solaris 10 box.

Snoop was not installed by default and I grabbed it from the Solaris 10 cd.
The package I installed was SUNWrcmdc as a man snoop shows it relies on this package.

Now when I run snoop as root, I get the following error:

ld.so.1: snoop: fatal: relocation error: file /usr/sbin/snoop: symbol dlpi_passive: referenced symbol not found

Sounds like a library path error. So I did a

host# ldd -r /usr/sbin/snoop

```
    libdhcputil.so.1 =>      /lib/libdhcputil.so.1
    libdlpi.so.1 =>  /lib/libdlpi.so.1
    libdlpi.so.1 (SUNWprivate_1.1) =>        (version not found)
    libsocket.so.1 =>        /lib/libsocket.so.1
    libnsl.so.1 =>   /lib/libnsl.so.1
    libtsol.so.2 =>  /lib/libtsol.so.2
    libc.so.1 =>     /lib/libc.so.1
    libgen.so.1 =>   /lib/libgen.so.1
    libinetutil.so.1 =>      /lib/libinetutil.so.1
    libmp.so.2 =>    /lib/libmp.so.2
    libmd.so.1 =>    /lib/libmd.so.1
    libscf.so.1 =>   /lib/libscf.so.1
    libdoor.so.1 =>  /lib/libdoor.so.1
    libsecdb.so.1 =>         /lib/libsecdb.so.1
    libuutil.so.1 =>         /lib/libuutil.so.1
    libcmd.so.1 =>   /lib/libcmd.so.1
    /platform/SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T5120/lib/libc_psr.so.1
    symbol not found: dlpi_passive          (/usr/sbin/snoop)
    /platform/SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T5120/lib/libmd_psr.so.1
    libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2
```

I picked up the latest patch for libdlpi.so.1 which is Patch 145923-02 and applied it. Didn't help. Same problem.

I don't know what to do about this "symbol not found: dlpi_passive"
I'm not sure what else I can try.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be a release mismatch.

What says

```
cat /etc/release
cat /cdrom/Solaris_10/Product/SUNWsolnm/reloc/etc/release
```

You probably need to adjust the path to the package on your CD or DVD.